# Android how to highlight and add a x (remove) button on edittext per word

Tags: java, android

I want to create an EditText like this:

[image: What I wanted]

I can't find something like this floating around the internet so I decided to ask it here. How could I create an EditText like in the picture?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the
[TagsEditText](https://github.com/mabbas007/TagsEditText) is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some libraries to help you get what you want to,

1. [Chips EditText Library](https://github.com/kpbird/chips-edittext-library)
2. [Android Chips](https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips)
3. [Chips Android](https://github.com/eyeem/chips-android)
4. [ChipView](https://github.com/Plumillon/ChipView)

Choose the one that suits you the best for your app's requirements. Hope it helps.